# error while running " npm run server " command

Tags: angular, npm, server

> '.' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
> operable program or batch file.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

update package.json to :

> "server": "ts-node -P server/server.tsconfig.json server/server.ts".

it directly access .bin in the node_module